# How to clear data from a range of cells based on another cells text?

Tags: excel, vba

Its been years since ive done VB and have found similar posts regarding a code im trying to create but honestly am struggling to adapt the answers to a macro i need.

Essentially cell D6 is will have a "Y" or "N" value and i need every time the value is changed to "N" the range D16:D500 contents to be cleared. I've tried

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$D$"6)) Is Nothing Then _
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$D$16:$D$500").ClearContents
End Sub
```

but cant get it to run. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You had a misplaced quote in your original code. Try this, which checks the value of D6. This code needs to go in the respective sheet module - right-click the sheet tab, View Code, and paste.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$6" Then
    If UCase(Target.Value) = "N" Then Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$D$16:$D$500").ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to make your code work as you were almost there.
For a better code, check SJR's answer (including the "Y"/"N" part).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$D$" & 6)) Is Nothing Then  ' Here you were missing a "&" or the 6 had to be in the quote
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$D$16:$D$500").ClearContents
    End If 'here you forgot to close the End If

End Sub
```

Finally, the common mistake here would be to post the code in the module instead of the sheet in VBA.